# How can I filter a dataframe with undetermined number of columns using R?

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr

I would like to be able to filter (preferable with Dplyr) several data frames with undetermined number of columns. Those data frames have several columns, some of them named with the same suffix. So, what I want to do is to filter those rows in which all the columns that are named using the same suffix have the same value.

So I have the following dataframe:

```
  Consequence CANONICAL x_LOH y_LOH x3
1            x       YES False False 12
2            x        NO False False 43
3            x       YES False False 64
4            x        NO  True False 34
5            y       YES  True False 93
6            y        NO  True False 16
7            y       YES  True  True 32
8            y        NO  True  True 74
9            z       YES False  True 84
10           z        NO False  True 89
```

I want to filter the data frame and select only those rows in which the columns that have the suffix (_LOH) are "True" ( attention!!: in this data frame are 2 columns but maybe in other data frames there is just one, or three, or four the columns with the suffix, I need the code to be useful for all the cases)

The desired output would be:

```
7            y       YES  True  True 32
8            y        NO  True  True 74
```

The code:

```
library(dplyr)

# Dataframe:

DF <- data.frame(Consequence = c(rep("x",4),rep("y",4),rep("z",4)),
                       CANONICAL = rep(c("YES","NO"),6),
                       x_LOH = c(rep("False", 3), rep("True", 5), rep("False",2), "True","False"),
                       y_LOH = c(rep("False", 6), rep("True",4), rep("False",2)),
                       x3=c(12,43,64,34,93,16,32,74,84,89,45,67))

# This obviously does not work

cols = names(DF)[grepl("_LOH", names(DF))]
DF %>% filter
 (for(i in 1:length(cols)){
   cols[i] == "True"
})
```

Any idea will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
DF %>%
 filter_at(vars(ends_with("_LOH")), all_vars(. == "True"))

  Consequence CANONICAL x_LOH y_LOH x3
1           y       YES  True  True 32
2           y        NO  True  True 74
```

Similarly with `base R`:

```
ind <- endsWith(names(DF), "_LOH")
DF[rowSums(DF[, ind] == "True") == sum(ind), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, we can select the columns which ends with `"LOH"` and select rows where all values are `"True"`

```
cols <- grep("_LOH$", names(DF))
DF[rowSums(DF[cols] == "True") == length(cols), ]

#  Consequence CANONICAL x_LOH y_LOH x3
#7           y       YES  True  True 32
#8           y        NO  True  True 74
```

---

Or using `apply`

```
DF[apply(DF[cols] == "True", 1, all), ]
```

Here, this will also work but with a warning stating that character values are coerced to logical.

```
DF[apply(DF[cols], 1, all), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

One more base R option:

```
isT <- function(x, y) x == "True" & y == "True"
subset(DF, Reduce(isT, DF[endsWith(names(DF), "_LOH")]), )

#   Consequence CANONICAL x_LOH y_LOH x3
# 7           y       YES  True  True 32
# 8           y        NO  True  True 74
```